# Adding Default custom fields to pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add some default custom fields only to the pages in wordpress with this code at my functions.php:

```
// Adding Custom Fields
add_action('save_post', 'set_default_custom_fields', '99');
function set_default_custom_fields($post_id){
    if ( $_GET['post_type'] == 'page' ) {

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'Header', '', true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'Überschrift', '', true);

    }
}
```

The custom fields are showing by adding a new page but not if I EDIT a existing page. If a page is still there and "published" it will not be showing. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Advanced Custom Fields. It's a free plugin with adds custom fields to any post_type, so also to pages.

http://advancedcustomfields.com
It can also be implemented into your php code.
It works really great!

Good luck!